# InvalidCastException when running a query that returns a number

Tags: c#, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I have a query...

```
select
real_arrival_date-planned_delivery_date as days_late
from ifsapp.purchase_receipt_statistics
```

where `real_arrival_date` and `planned_arrival_date` are columns of type `date`. The resulting `days_late` will be a decimal number indicating how many days late our purchases arrived.

I execute this in C# using the Oracle Managed Client (though I suspect the regular unmanaged ODP.NET client will have this problem too).

```
var command = new OracleCommand("select real_arrival_date-planned_delivery_date as days_late from ifsapp.purchase_receipt_statistics");
var result = GetDataTable(command);

public static DataTable GetDataTable(OracleCommand command)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (var connection = GetDefaultOracleConnection())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader()); //InvalidCastException here
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I get an `InvalidCastException` at the indicated spot in the code. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the results of subtracting two date columns in Oracle can have a really long decimal number, example: `54.4514351851852`. The Oracle client isn't prepared to convert that into a C# `decimal`, thus you get an `InvalidCastException` on what looks like a rather straightforward query.

The fix is to round the number off using Oracle's `ROUND()` function. Change the query like this to round it to two decimal places:

```
select
ROUND(real_arrival_date-planned_delivery_date, 2) as days_late
from ifsapp.purchase_receipt_statistics
```

The Oracle client will then be able to successfully convert the value to a decimal, and the function will execute without an issue.